# Vary DNS resolution according to requesting IP

Tags: dns, ip, reverse-lookup

I'm looking for a way of getting our DNS server to do a reverse look-up in order to resolve placeholder values differently according to the requesting machine's IP address.

#### Variables

- A placeholder value called **SYSWEB** to be resolved by DNS
- Websites: **www.website.dev.net** and **www.website.uat.net**
- Machines: **Machine1** and **Machine2**

#### Conditions

- If Machine1 attempts to connect to SYSWEB, the DNS server will
  resolve it to www.website.dev.net
- If Machine2 attempts to connect to SYSWEB, the DNS server will
  resolve it to www.website.uat.net

I've already tried to do this with BIND DNS, following the implementation laid out [here](http://ipamworldwide.com/view-declarations.html), but I have not made any progress worth noting....

The main problem I'm having is that I cannot allow the DNS to resolve an IP address from the placeholder value, it **needs** to be a domain name.

Surely someone out there has successfully done what I'm failing to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two separate zone files and route access to the correct zone file based on views. This is usually called *split-horizon DNS* and there are plenty of examples on the net, e.g.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/#split-view

http://www.knowplace.org/pages/howtos/split_view_with_bind_9_howto.php